# Install WordPress on a add on domain in Hetzner hosting

Tags: linux, wordpress, hosting

I am new to Hetzner so I am sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Long story short, this is my situation:

I have 2 WordPress Websites and each of them is hosted in a different hosting, from a different hosting provider (not Hetzner).

My goal is to host both of my WordPress Websites in one account on Hetzner (one hosting).
I asked this question before and I got told that I should buy Web Hosting Level 9 package, so that I can add both of my sites as add on domains and that they can be literally 2 different WordPress Websites but they would have the same hosting (site1.com and site2.com , but same host).

And I did just that. I purchased Web Hosting Level 9 package and during the purchasing process I had to claim a free domain. I did that and used "aisolutionmontenegro.com" , but I don't plan on don't anything with this particular domain.

Now after that I added the domain my first WordPress Website as a add on domain, and it showed up.

The problem that I am facing is that I want to install WordPress to this first add on domain, but I can not see the option "WordPress" on the Services part, like I see it when I am on the main domain that I claimed for free "aisolutionmontenegro.com".

[The domain I claimed for free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqTLw.jpg)

Remember, I don't need aisolutionmontenegro.com at all, I just want to add two add on domains and on each of them install WordPress. Is that possible and how?

[The domain of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09qhF.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

When I added the "main" domain with I claimed for free while buying Web Host Level 9 package from Hetzner, I had to go to "Products" and then select the "main" domain.

After I selected the main domain, in the left side menu, go to Services and you can see there WordPress. We click WordPress and then go to the installation process.

During the installation process you have to choose a root directory for your site, and here is where you need to be careful.

If you want to install your WordPress site on an add on domain (let's assume its called "site1.com") then you need for the root directory to create a new folder called the name of your site (in this case create a folder "site1").

After that you can continue with the installation process normally.

And for every add on domain that we want to install WordPress on we do the same thing, we click on the "main" domain, and then we click WordPress. During the installation process as the root directory we create a new folder called like the add on domain (for example our second add on domain is called "site2.com", we create a folder called "site2").